# Ubuntu 11.10 GRUB and windows 7

Tags: grub2

I have a dual boot system (Windows7 and Ubuntu 11.10). When I start my system grub shows first, then if I choose Windows7, it then shows the Windows7 boot loader.

The problem now is that I have formatted my Ubuntu partition, so anytime I turn up my system, I get this error:

```
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you've formatted your Ubuntu partition you will need to re-install. It appears GRUB cannot find a valid Linux operating system, can you add the details of what you did in regards to 'formatting' to your question?

Answer (score 2):

If you deleted Ubuntu and your system was using the partition where Ubuntu was to keep the boot loader you need to fix your MBR and use the Windows7 boot loader if you don't want to install Ubuntu again.

Use the Windows7 CD to fix your MBR and boot loader.

More information on the Microsoft Support site under this page

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'v repaired the mbr using a windows installation disc, and that solved the problem.

Comment: Mark it solved then please, one less in the list. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use your Ubuntu live CD to repair your boot loader. This link about [Repairing Grub](http://ubuntutechnical.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/install-windows-after-ubuntu-is-installed/) can help you.